# Mangeto how to get session subtotal value?

Tags: magento, subtotal

I am currently using magento 1.9.1 and i'm trying to get the session subtotal value in external file.

So here it is the code that i am working around with:

```
    <?PHP
    require('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento

    Mage::app();
    echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); 
    ?>
```

The problem is that when i execute this script i receive blank screen. No value is displayed.

This is all the code in this php page.

What i am doing wrong, can you help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at var/log/exception.log or var/log/system.log file

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() ?>
```

To see whats behind the white screen:

Goto index.php and uncomment the following line:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```